# Calculate angle for points of circle that intersect with rect

Tags: ios, geometry, core-graphics

I would like to start with saying that I am not terribly skilled in maths. Please excuse if my problem seems trivial to you, but I cant quite wrap my head around it.

I need to distribute and align some views on a circle with a given radius and center. That really is no problem and I already have that working great. I can even specify a maximum and a minimum angle for the alignment circle, so my views will only be distributes over a half-circle or something similar.

To provide better insight, here is my code:

```
    var minAngle: Double = 270
    var maxAngle: Double = 630
    var i = 0
    let maxIndizes = isFullCircle(minAngle, maxAngle: maxAngle) ? subviews.count : subviews.count - 1

    subviews.forEach { (subview: UIView) -> () in
        let angle = getAngleForIndex(i, max: maxIndizes, minAngle: minAngle, maxAngle: maxAngle)
        let radius = Double(bounds.width / 2)
        let circlePos = getPointForAngle(angle, radius: radius)

        let view = UIView()
        addSubview(view)
        view.center = circlePos

        i++
    }
```

The problem is, that all of my views have to be in a given rectangle. Depending on the center of my circle, some views might be placed outside of the rectangle and thus, offscreen.

To fix that problem I am trying to only use a semi circle if a full circle does not fit inside my rectangle. As said previously my code already works using semi circles by specifying a different `minAngle` or `maxAngle`. The problem is that I have no idea on how to calculate the `minAngle` and `maxAngle` so that the semi circle fits my rectangle.

To further clarify my problem, I tried illustrating it:

[image: Illustration]

**TL;DR:** I need to calculate the angle for the intersections between the rectangle and the circle marked by the arrows.

*Additional information:*

- The circles diameter is always less than the rectangles width or height
- The app is targeting iOS 9
- Any code is written in Swift 2, so it may require Xcode 7

Comment: Note: In general, a circle (diameter < width and dia. < height) and a rectangle can have 0,1,2,3 or 4 different intersections - not necessarily 2 as diagrammed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's circle center is (cx, cy), raidus R, and top-left and right-bottom corners of rectangle are (x1,y1)-(x2,y2)

Solve equations like this (this one is for left edge of rectangle)

```
(x1-cx)^2 + (y-cy)^2 = R^2
```

If solution for y exists, check whether Y found (one or two solutions) is in range [y1..y2]. If so, calculate angle for this intersection

```
Fi = atan2(y-cy, x1-cx)
```